# How can I change what faction I am "Closest To"?

Tags: fallen-london

As the early parts of Fallen London wind down, you meet the Numismatrix, who (partially) explains the many different currencies in the game, and invites you to choose a faction to be *Closest To*. She promised that I would be able to change which faction I'm *Closest To* at some point in the future. I initially chose to be close to Hell, because I was becoming intimate of devils at the time. But those d----d hellspawn just wanted to get their hands on my immortal soul!

I'm starting to think that my choice of faction was hasty, and that I would prefer to join a group I can identify with. Some level-headed people. A more human group — the Revolutionaries, perhaps. I mean, all *they* want to do is end society as I know it, which is certainly a step in a safer direction.

So: How can I change the faction that I am *Closest To*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About January 14th, 2014, there was a change to the faction cards: each faction card now has a storylet to abandon that faction (losing your *Closest To* quality entirely, along with every single bit of your *Connected: [that faction]*), and a second storylet to become *Closest To* that faction if you're not close to anybody.

Becoming *Closest To* a faction is quite expensive: it usually costs several of an item that you can only acquire through the Bazaar Sidestreets and/or the Relickers – for instance, becoming *Closest To: Hell* requires 5 Portfolios of Souls, and becoming *Closest To: Tomb-Colonists* requires two Parabola-Linen. Those high-level items take around 160 Certifiable Scrap per unit, so becoming a *Person of Some Importance* and visiting the Bazaar Sidestreets is usually easier than acquiring a truly heroic amount of Certifiable Scrap. (Even if you're not yet a *Person of Some Importance*, it's *still* easier to become one than it is to acquire the 300-plus Scrap!)

At the moment, the faction that you're *Closest To* only affects your ability to participate in the various *Counting the Days* storylets, which are mostly on opportunity cards. These are more-or-less balanced across the factions, with two striking exceptions: both the Great Game and the Bohemians have access to both of the always-available storylets *Dice games on the quayside* and *Seeking Curios and Secrets in the Forgotten Quarter* that will raise your *Counting the Days* quality if it's in a certain range. The "low-class" factions can only access the first storylet (taking *Counting the Days* from 0 to 6), and the "high-class" factions can only access the latter storylet (taking *Counting the Days* from 6 to 10). This means that getting up to *Counting the Days 10* is fast and easy if you're *Closest To* the Bohemians or the Great Game.

The other way to change your *Closest to To* is to sell the location of the Cave of the Nadir to one of four factions: Hell, the Urchins, the Great Game, or the Revolutionaries. This will give you a pile of *Connected: [faction]*, a highly-valuable item, and will change your *Closest To* to the chosen faction. (Finding and completing the Cave of the Nadir is a long storyline outside the scope of this answer.)